# Can not redirect http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com IIS

Tags: c#, redirect, iis

```
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Redirect to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" ignoreCase="true" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain.com" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>


                <rule name="Redirect HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
```

Guys, im stuck at this for 2 hours, please help, these are my 2 rules which, if you type in browser "domain.com" should redirect you to "https://www.domain.com"
my certificate is registered on "www.domain.com" so i need to add the www in fron of my domain and make it work when people type in browser domain.com to redirect them to www.domain.com with HTTPS enabled. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
<rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```